# Workaround to tf.where() shape output

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am wondering if there is a way to get around the array shape that tf.where() outputs. For example here is the code I am trying to run:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.constant([[[1,0],[0,2]],[[0,3],[4,0]]]).eval()
    c = tf.where(tf.equal(a,0)).eval()
    c = tf.multiply(100,c).eval()
    c = tf.add(a,c)

    print(c.eval())
```

What I expected the output would be is:

```
[[[  1,100]
  [100,  2]

 [[100,  3]
  [  4,100]]]
```

However, there is an error due to the fact that the way tf.where() outputs my code is as a 4x3 tensor rather than a 2x2x2. Is there another command set I can use to effectively replace all zeros with 100's? This method works for a 2-D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a tensor of 100's, and then use that in the `where` call. As per [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where), this function takes two optional tensors to read values.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.constant([[[1,0],[0,2]],[[0,3],[4,0]]])
    h = tf.multiply(tf.ones(a.shape, tf.int32), 100)
    c = tf.where(tf.equal(a, 0), h, a)

    print(c.eval())
```